# Python ImportError on Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, but not on 3.9

Tags: python

I have come across a bizarre import error on my CI that I can't reproduce locally, and have no idea how to tackle. I use Azure pipelines for my CI and run a build matrix to build wheels for my package. Everything is built as expected. Today, I wanted to release a new version and I changed the code a little bit. My file structure is

```py
openTSNE/
   __init__.py
   utils.py
tests/
   test_tsne.py
setup.py
```

so the source is in `openTSNE` and the tests are in the `tests` folder. I attempt to import the function `is_package_installed`  in `test_tsne.py`  from `openTSNE.utils` like so

```py
from openTSNE.utils import is_package_installed
```

I build the wheels for all versions of Python 3.6 - 3.9, on Mac, Windows, and Linux. I also build an sdist on Linux. I first build the packages on each CI VM, install it, and run my unittest suite on the installed package.

That's the setup. Here's the absolutely bizarre part:
Everything works on my wheels OSX-py39, Win-py39, and all linux wheels. It does *NOT* work on the Linux sdist version, or on OSX-py36 through py38, or on Win-py36 through py38. See the CI build log
https://dev.azure.com/pavlingp/openTSNE/_build/results?buildId=359&view=logs&j=9adead4c-7271-5cd3-b143-2c28e08460f5&t=9572adb2-9d5f-5130-5c60-5fd15aeb658c

The tests fail with

```
tests/test_tsne.py:19: in <module>
from openTSNE.utils import is_package_installed
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_package_installed'
```

The source code can be found on GH. The [function](https://github.com/pavlin-policar/openTSNE/blob/master/openTSNE/utils.py#L37-L45) and the [offending test](https://github.com/pavlin-policar/openTSNE/blob/master/tests/test_nearest_neighbors.py#L12). I have tried to reproduce this on my local MacBook without success.

I am at a loss of what could be going wrong. This is also the first time this has happened, I've been working on this project for a while without any such issues. Any help or pointer in the right direction, or even how I could approach debugging/reproducing this would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: What is the last version (commit) where it still worked?

Comment: So, this is a bit tricky. The package is pretty stable, so the last time I ran the release pipeline was in August on 8d65297. However, I'm certain it should have worked up until 95dfe72. Since then, I added Python 3.9 wheels, which required me to switch from manylinux1 to manlinux2010 image for Linux builds, I had to bump the minimum numpy requirement from 1.14.6 to 1.16.6, and I've added *-mmacosx-version-min=10.12* linker flag to mac builds to be compatible with older versions. However, none of that should affect this import error.

Comment: The log files for the **Install wheel** step reveal that for all versions except 3.9, the package has been retrieved from `pypi.org` instead of using the local file (compare [3.8: line 125](https://dev.azure.com/pavlingp/5cb66a81-2133-497d-b709-28a391e897b8/_apis/build/builds/359/logs/153) vs. [3.9: line 116](https://dev.azure.com/pavlingp/5cb66a81-2133-497d-b709-28a391e897b8/_apis/build/builds/359/logs/201)). You're specifying `python -m pip install -vv --force-reinstall --find-links dist openTSNE` so it just installs a version that matches.

Answer (score 2):

I have tracked down the issue. When I was running the CI builds, I hadn't bumped the version. The live version on PyPI is 0.4.4, and I was working on releasing v0.5.0. However, I hadn't bumped the version in the package, so when I was building wheels and the sdist package, they were being tagged with 0.4.4.

Now, I had tried to get around this by running pip with the `--find-links` switch

```
pip install --user --force-reinstall --find-links dist openTSNE
```

I was, however, not aware that pip will **always** prioritize packages on the PyPI over local binaries or sdists. So, on my CI servers, I was building the wheels, but when I actually installed them to run the unit tests, pip was pulling down 0.4.4 from PyPI and not using the newly built package. This is why the import error was occurring -- I had only added the offending `is_package_installed`  function in this version, and it didn't exist in 0.4.4.

Bumping the version fixed the problem, as pip wasn't able to find 0.5.0 on PyPI and was forced to use the local binary.

It is bizarre to me that it doesn't behave in the same way on all platforms, yet here we are.

Comment: Well, it works for every platform / Python version combination for which wheels are available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/openTSNE/0.4.4/#files) (for version 0.4.4). This includes everything except Python 3.9 and the Linux platform since you switched to `manylinux2010_x86_64` (and wheels are available for `manylinux1_x86_64`).

Comment: Oh, I see, that's what's different about the Linux builds. Thanks! That clears things up.

Comment: If you want to run the CI before/without bumping the version number, you can do so in the CI script, e.g. by appending a [dev version](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#developmental-releases).

Comment: That's a fantastic suggestion. Thank you! I'll definitely do this next time I need to work on my release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a  **init**.py file?

```
openTSNE/
utils.py/
__init__.py
tests/
test_tsne.py
setup.py
```

If you remove the **init**.py file, Python will no longer look for submodules inside that directory, so attempts to import the module will fail.

The **init**.py file is usually empty, but can be used to export selected portions of the package under more convenient name, hold convenience functions, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course. I didn't explicitly add it to my question, since I thought it would be clear from the context, and I didn't want to clutter the question with the full file list. If I missed __init__.py, it wouldn't work on any python version on any platform. I also linked the GH repo, so you can take a look at the full project.